# Microsoft Team - Create new team with predefine language for underlying SharePoint site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

Our Microsoft 365 is configured with *Danish* as default language, as a consequence is the language of all SharePoint team sites that are automatically created by Microsoft 365 when creating a new team also using *Danish*. This is a problem because the document library is using `https://foobar.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Delte%20dokumenter/Forms/AllItems.aspx` instead of `https://foobar.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx` as URL.

I am now trying to find a way to create multiple teams (50+) where the language of the SPO site is *English* instead of *Danish*.

I have already tried the following concepts without success

1. **Approach 1**: Use a team-template when creating a new team, the language defined by the template does not affect the language of the SPO site.
2. **Approach 2**: Creating unified group first and than convert unified-group into team: The language of cmdlet [New-UnifiedGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/exchange/new-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps) does not affect the language of the SPO site
3. **Approach 3**: Create SPO site with PowerShell first and than create team based on this site. A similar concept is covered in blog article
   [Create a Team From Existing SharePoint Online Modern Team Site Using PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-team-from-existing-sharepoint-online-modern-team-site-using-powershell), but the problem is the fact that I cannot create a group-enabled team-site using PowerShell, when using template `STS#3` - the attempt to create a new SPO site using template `GROUP#0` results in error (`The web template GROUP#0 is not available for sites on this tenant`)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution: Use the cmdlet `Set-SPOSiteOffice365Group`

My approach includes now the following step:

1. Create a SPO team site with PowerShell (not related to a unified group). Defined the correct /needed language via parameter `LocaleId`.
2. Use `Set-SPOSiteOffice365Group` - this will create a new unified group and that will use the exiting SPO team-site
3. Convert the unified group into team, see [Creating a New Microsoft 365 Group with the Microsoft PowerShell Graph SDK](https://practical365.com/create-new-microsoft-365-group-sdk/)